# "My one" vs Mine

Tags: grammar, pronouns, possessives

I've heard someone say "Here's my one" instead of "Here's mine". Is the former grammatical? It seems like it's a shortcut for "Here's one that is mine".

Comment: No, it is not correct if the meaning "Here's mine" is implied. It would be correct with some other meaning like "Here's my one-dollar bill".

Comment: @Vilmar I don't see what is incorrect about it. 'You don't have an umbrella with you?. Well, if you need to go out use my one'. It is not used as often as 'mine', but I don't see what's wrong with it. After all 'mine' is simply an abbreviation of 'my one'.

Comment: "Here's my one" means "Here's **the** one that is mine" rather than just any of the articles in question that I possess.

Comment: I'd say that, as 'Here are my two / three / four / ...' are all perfectly acceptable, arguing that 'Here is my one' isn't acceptable for 'Here is mine; I only have the one' is very dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a very common usage but it would technically be grammatically correct.

> Where are your crayons? Here is mine.
>
> Where are your crayons? Here is my crayon.
>
> Where are your crayons? Here is my crayons.
>
> Where are your crayons? Here are my two crayons.
>
> Where are your crayons? Here is my one crayon.
>
> Where are your crayons? Here is my one.
>
> Where are your crayons? Here are my two.

The last two examples sound very strange to my ear and I would never use them. But I am unaware of a rule that dictates they are improper.

Comment: "Here is my crayons" should be "Here are my crayons" surely?

Answer (score 0):

"Here is my one car. Here are my two cars. Here are my two."
'Here are my two cars' would be used to compare my two cars to your two cars but "My one car" doesn't make grammatical sense just like saying " your one". It's almost childlike grammar and shouldn't be used.
There are nuances to the languages which dictate that certain phrases are not correct. "This is my one/your one" is not correct by a mile. Sorry.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).